# System bar not showing when using the macbuntu theme

Tags: 11.04, compiz

i think i really need your assistance in this.I've installed ubuntu 10.10 and this [mac theme](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/03/02/how-to-install-mac-theme-on-ubuntu-10-10/) and so far it works fine. This morning i upgraded to `11.04` and it also went well. i just realise some of the effects were gone. so i open compizconfig settings manager, i've tried to enable the destop cube and the expo and it prompted me of desabling somethings here and there.
 honestly i went fast couldn't undo what i've done and i realize the new application launcher and the system bar weren't showing properly, so i decided to restart my machine.After that 'bummer', nothing were like before.no system bar, no application launcher, not menu bar for any of my applications not even for the console.
How i'm going to solve this one this time.

thanks for reading this and specially for helping out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Macbuntu**, according to its own site, is not compatible with **Unity**.  After you downloaded it, you extracted it into a directory. If you've deleted that directory, re-download and re-extract.

- Open a terminal, run `cd
  /path/to/the/macbuntu/folder/`
- In that same terminal, run
  `./uninstall.sh`

This should remove **Macbuntu**.  If it does not, please read its README and/or contact the developer for support.

Now we need to fix Unity.

- Go to the terminal and type `gksu
  synaptic`. You will be prompted for your password.
- Type **Unity** in the quick filter bar.

[image]

- Right click on the **Unity** package
  (in the list in the middle of the
  window), and choose **Mark for
  Reinstallation**.

[image]

- Click the apply button, and wait for
  the changes to finish.

[image]

- Close Synaptic, and the terminal. 
  You may need to log out and back in
  to see the changes.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. the "./uninstall.sh force" command successfully uninstall Macbuntu, i've installed the unity but after a restart still system bar, and unity are not back :(

Comment: Could you try "unity --reset" from the command line?

Comment: hello it came but outputs this http://pastie.org/1868779 and it's seems like it's running from the console since it doesn't return the prompt

Comment: Press <Ctrl>+Z in the console, then type "bg" then "disown".  Note that your window system might break when you press <Ctrl>+Z, so read the whole answer before you start!

Comment: errm sorry i left my laptop and my bro not knowing what was happening log me off, when i log back in everything was like normal.i then restarted and it seems back to normal. i think that's it. is there anything i have to do again?

Comment: You're probably good.  I think the --reset flag caused it to fix your configuration.  It should work.

Comment: thank Kevin, if i could i would give you like 10 points. :)) you save my day. see you around ;)

Comment: Hello everyone i think there is still something odd. i still dont have title bars for all apps. i though the new ubuntu came with that feature that's one of the reason why i didn't notice right away.How to get the title bars back. thanks for everything

Comment: Open compizconfig settings manager, click "effects" on the left, and uncheck and re-check the Window Decoration plugin.  If that doesn't work, run `compiz-decorator & disown` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me and i think i have your solution
(or at least this is what work for me)

boot up in **Ubuntu classic** and go to **system - administration - synaptic package manager**
remove anything that has to do with **compiz** (or anything that has compiz in the name)

now restart your computer and boot up in **Ubuntu** and press **ctrl alt t** and your **terminal** should come up type in this line **sudo apt-get install compiz** then press enter after that type in this line **sudo apt-get install unity** press enter then **sudo apt-get upgrade unity**

after its done restart your computer and boot in to **ubuntu** and bam everything is back

Comment: when you did so, did you have the expo and the cube desktop working?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a compiz problem, though I may be wrong. Try pressing Alt+F2 to open the quick launcher. From here you can start programs, like the compiz settings manager. To do this, try typing "ccsm" into the launcher.
There, you can turn off the cube again. Hope this works for you.

edit: If you can open the settings manager, you may want to turn off the Unity-Plugin, and then on again.

If you can't use Alt+F2, maybe you can log into a different session (Ubuntu Classic (no effects)) at login and correct it like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i still have the dock "docky" and i've turned off everything under desktop submenu and it still seems not working even after restart.

Comment: Just tried it myself, the cube seems to collide with desktop wall. Can you turn that and unity plugin on again? does it help?

Comment: thank you for your time. Kevin's approach worked for me.thanks